# how to preselect select tag's option using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains select tag, I want to prefill that tag after clicking on button on the previous page. how can I do this?
here's the form code:

```
<form method="post" name="registration" action="http://esafe.urdemo.net/user/login/signup" onsubmit="return checkform2();">

                                <input type="text" class="textbox"  placeholder="Enter First Name"   name="first_name" /> 

                               <input type="text" class="textbox"   placeholder="Enter Middle Name" name="middle_name" />

                               <input type="text" class="textbox"  placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="last_name" />

                               <input type="text" class="textbox"  placeholder="Select Date dd/mm/yyyy"  name="Date1" onblur="return checkdob(this);"/>

                               <input type="text" class="textbox"  placeholder="Enter Email Id" name="email" />

                               <input type="text" class="textbox"  placeholder="Enter Mobile No." name="mobile" />

                               <select name="plan" class="form-control"  style="width:90%">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="1">Pro</option>
                                    <option value="2">Premium</option>
                                    <option value="3">Elite</option>
                                    <option value="4">Magna</option>
                               </select>
 <div class="signinStrip">
  <span class="forgot"> <a href="#" id="resend_password_link"></a> </span>
   <input class="signin_submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

here's the button's code

```
 <tr>
     <td class="title">&nbsp;</td>
     <td><p class="bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" >Buy Now</a></p></td>
     <td><p class="bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" >Buy Now</a></p></td>
     <td><p class="bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" >Buy Now</a></p></td>
     <td><p class="bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" >Buy Now</a></p></td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: what do you mean by prefill? do you want to select a particular option on the based of previous page button click or you want to fill the select box with new options

Comment: @Sandeeproop, yes I want to select a particular option based on button clicked on the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select particular option based on button clicked on previous page then you have  to send that value via some server side variable or via address url param. for eg. your second page url has to be something like "http://yourdomain.com/page2?selected_value=temp"

Then in next page javascript you have to extract this param

```
function getParam(paramName) {
  return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(paramName + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
  );
} 
var selectedVal = getParam("elected_value");
document.getElementById(<your select box id>).value = selectedVal;​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: the way you suggested is sending params through get request right? I want to send it through post request.

Comment: Then you can set them in some server variable and pass those to JS variable on next page eg. var select_val = <%= @selected %> in rails